# Problema con una lista en soap web service java

Tags: java, lista, webservice, soap, jdeveloper

estoy haciendo una aplicación que implementa Soap WebService en jDeveloper, la cuestión es que necesito listar en un jTable la información de una tabla llamada Pacientes alojada en mi base de datos, para esto tengo una aplicación para el servidor y otra para el cliente. en la del servidor tengo el siguiente método para listar:

```
public static List listar(){
           List<Paciente> listaPaciente = new ArrayList<>();
            String sql = "select * from paciente";
          
            try {
                con = conectar.getConnection();
               
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    Paciente p = new Paciente();
                    p.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    p.setDocumento(rs.getString(2));
                    p.setNombre(rs.getString(3));
                    p.setCorreo(rs.getString(4));
                    p.setTelefono(rs.getString(5));
                    p.setGenero(rs.getString(6));
                    listaPaceinte.add(p);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
            
            return listaPaciente;
             
            }
```

en la aplicación cliente simplemente implemento el wsdl y se me generan todos los metodos alojados en mi servidor, pero a la hora de llamar el metodo listar tengo el siguiente incoveniente.

```
 public void listarPacientes() 
    {
       DafaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel)guiListarP.jTablePacientes.getModel();
       
        
              // ACA ES EL ERROR
              List<Paciente> lista =  pacienteSW.listar();
                
               
               Object[]object = new Object[5];
               for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
               {
                   object[0] = lista.get(i).getDocumento();
                   object[1] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
                   object[2] = lista.get(i).getCorreo();
                   object[3] = lista.get(i).getTelefono();
                   object[4] = lista.get(i).getGenero();  
                   modelo.addRow(object);
               }
               
               //guiL.jTableListar.setModel(modelo);
                //modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
               
        
    }
```

me dice que Error(144,61): incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<serviciosweb.Paciente>

sericiosweb es el paquete que se me genero automáticamente al implementar el servidor en mi cliente, al igual que pacienteSW.

clase a la cual pertenece pacienteSW

```
package serviciosweb;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.3.0-b170214.1743
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 *
 */
@WebService(name = "PacienteSW", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/")
@XmlSeeAlso({ ObjectFactory.class })
public interface PacienteSW {


    /**
     *
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns int
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "agregarPaciente", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                    className = "serviciosweb.AgregarPaciente")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "agregarPacienteResponse", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                     className = "serviciosweb.AgregarPacienteResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/agregarPacienteRequest",
            output = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/agregarPacienteResponse")
    public int agregarPaciente(@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "") Paciente arg0);

    /**
     *
     * @param arg1
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns int
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "modificarPaciente", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                    className = "serviciosweb.ModificarPaciente")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "modificarPacienteResponse", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                     className = "serviciosweb.ModificarPacienteResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/modificarPacienteRequest",
            output = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/modificarPacienteResponse")
    public int modificarPaciente(@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "") Paciente arg0,
                                 @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "") String arg1);

    /**
     *
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns serviciosweb.Paciente
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "buscarPaciente", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                    className = "serviciosweb.BuscarPaciente")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "buscarPacienteResponse", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                     className = "serviciosweb.BuscarPacienteResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/buscarPacienteRequest",
            output = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/buscarPacienteResponse")
    public Paciente buscarPaciente(@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "") String arg0);

    /**
     *
     * @param arg0
     */
    @WebMethod
    @Oneway
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "eliminarPaciente", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                    className = "serviciosweb.EliminarPaciente")
    @Action(input = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/eliminarPaciente")
    public void eliminarPaciente(@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "") String arg0);

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns java.util.List<java.lang.Object>
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "listar", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/", className = "serviciosweb.Listar")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "listarResponse", targetNamespace = "http://serviciosWeb/",
                     className = "serviciosweb.ListarResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/listarRequest",
            output = "http://serviciosWeb/PacienteSW/listarResponse")
    public List<Object> listar();

}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: Hola Sebas9981, ¿podrías colocar por favor la clase que le corresponde a la variable pacienteSW en el código del cliente?

Comment: Vale, ya la coloque

Comment: De acuerdo. Te pido que comentes el código que esta dentro del for y en lugar de el pongas: System.out.println("El tipo es: "+ o.getClass()); 

También te pido que cambies:

List<Paciente> lista =  pacienteSW.listar();

por

List<Object> lista =  pacienteSW.listar();

Y me digas en un comentario que te imprime (debería de compilar pero fallar, me interesa saber el tipo de dato que viene del servicio)

Comment: acabo de hacer una prueba, si en la clase PacienteSW cambio en el ultimo metodo, especificamente este  public List<Object> listar();, por list<Paciente>, ya no marca ningun error, compila y me lista la informacion de la base de datos., Pero aun asi no se si deberia hacer eso, aunque me sirva es una clase que fue generada automaticamente y no se si deberia tocarla.

Comment: Ya veo. Si, prueba a dejarla como estaba y en tu codigo donde haces. List<Paciente> lista =  pacienteSW.listar();   cambialo por List<Paciente> lista =  (List<Paciente>)pacienteSW.listar();

Comment: ya intente castearla y sigue marcando el mismo error, lo unico que me funciono por ahora es lo que te mencione anteriormente.

Comment: De acuerdo. Bueno pues entonces para no mover el código autogenerado puedes declarar lista como: List<Object> lista =  pacienteSW.listar();
Luego en el cuerpo del for pones:    Paciente  paciente: (Paciente)lista.get(i);  y cambias las instrucciones de la forma: object[0] = lista.get(i).getDocumento();  por object[0] = paciente.getDocumento();

Comment: Vale, lo intentare. Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo para responder todo.

Comment: No hay de que. Hoy por ti, mañana por uno.